# New to Prepared Statements, just doesn't feel secure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

The tablename will get compared against a whitelist of acceptable tables before hand by checking a table that list those tables. That list has to be dynamic which is why I opted out of using an array. Are the variables in the set variables section secure? They are coming user submitted post data.

```
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . mysql_real_escape_string($tablename) . "` (item_name, item_price, item_position, item_type, multi_link_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        //Build Parameters 
        $stmt->bind_param('sdiii', $additemnameb, $additempriceb, $itempositionb, $itemtypeb, $linkidb);

        //Set Variables
        $additemnameb = $additemname;
        $additempriceb = $additemprice;
        $itempositionb = $itemposition;
        $itemtypeb = $itemtype;
        $linkidb = $linkid;

        //Execute Statement
        $stmt->execute();

        //Close Statement
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
        //Errors
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
```

Edited to have an actual question to be clear what I'm concerned about.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: why are you using mysql_real_escape_string with mysqli? pick an extension (and note php_mysql is deprecated pending removal in 5.5). Prepared statements ARE secure :)

Comment: @Martin, the use of mysql_real_escape_string was an oversite while switching from the previous method. I'm concerned because the values are coming from user submitted POST data, it just feels dirty. I'm still learning PHP and a lot of what I have together is tutorials. Now I'm going through and implementing security while making changes to the code to make it my "own" trying to have a full understanding of every aspect, prepared statements is not yet part of that full understanding.

Comment: Instead of escaping `$tablename` it is much preferred to compare `$tablename` against an array of _acceptable_ table names. If it isn't in the whitelist, you don't execute the query.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I will get rid of the escape for tablename, but as I mentioned in my post I do plan to check it against a whitelist built from a separate table that is needed for a different reason, but happens to be perfect to use as a whitelist in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions YES the variables in the `// Set Variables` section are secure, or more technically the variables will become secure before the query is executed. Mysqli takes care of it for you.